# Why is my WP site blocking my own IP?

Tags: troubleshooting

Im stumped

- WP is hosted on a VPS
- Browser will not load anything
- curl returned connection refused
- SSH access to the VPS works
- UFW does not have any specific ip addresses blocked
- Apache logs do not show anything related
- I was running wordfence but disabled it as well as ALL other plugins and there was not change
- .htacess does not have anything blocked
- I can access the site from other IP addresses I.E when connected to my hotspot

Answer (score 0):

Since this actually seems to be a server related issue, it would be better suited for stackoverflow.com, or a stack exchange that is dedicated to networking.
But, I'll do my best to help here.

If the CURL is showing connection refused, the connection is getting blocked before it can even load WP. You could prove this by making a file in the root that just has [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and attempting to access it directly.

My guess is that the server is not configured to [listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) to the web ports. This would explain why you can access the server over your SSH port but not over the web.

Comment: It is listening on 443 with a redirect on port 80. If I connect to my hotspot or VPN I can load the site just fine.

Comment: Did you check IPTables?

Comment: Im running UFW(iptables frontend) and there are no ips blocked